# Запятая после "чуть-чуть"

Tags: пунктуация

"Еще чуть-чуть(,) и конец" — не пойму, нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы поставила тире, так как вторая часть содержит неожиданное присоединение.

**8 января.** Добавляю для тех, кто поставил  минус (подробнее и с опорой на справочники)

**Розенталь:** Если во второй части сложносочиненного предложения содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление, то между ними перед союзом вместо запятой ставится тире: Оковы тяжкие падут, темницы рухнут — и свобода вас примет радостно у входа (П.)...

Часто ставится тире, если первая часть сложносочиненного предложения или обе части являются номинативными (назывными) предложениями: **Ещё напор** — и враг бежит (П.); **Ещё одна минута** объяснения — и давнишняя вражда готова была погаснуть (Г.); Вот крик — и снова всё вокруг затихло (Л.); **Ещё несколько слов**, несколько ласк от матери — и крепкий сон овладел мною (Акс.); **Ещё единый миг** — и я паду к её ногам (А.К.Т.); **(***Не правда ли, очень похоже на еще чуть-чуть - и по смыслу, и отсутствием глагола -сказуемого?)*****

**Лопатин:**  Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится тире, если вторая часть предложения заключает в себе значение результата, следствия, резкого противопоставления (чаще перед союзом и, реже перед союзами но, а):

**Наумович:**

В отличие от запятой и точки запятой, которые являются знаками ССП открытой структуры, тире употребляется в ССП закрытой структуры при наличии союза и со значением обусловленности .
Все ССП с тире имеют ярко выраженный интонационный рисунок: конец первой предикативной части произносится с заметным повышением голоса, который перед союзами резко прерывается напряженной паузой ожидания. ***(Вполне соответствует нашему примеру)***.  Например: 
Еще один огромный взмах -
И спят ресницы.

И в качестве вывода:

Ориентируемся ли мы на значение (неожиданное присоединение, результат. следствие), на грамматическое выражение первой части (без глагола -сказуемого) или на особый интонационный рисунок - просится в предложение именно тире.

Comment: Вы меня не убедили :-). Наберите в Яндексе "ещё чуть-чуть и":

Ещё чуть-чуть, и в жизнь другую пойдут питомцы ваши...

ещё чуть-чуть, и подойду...

Ещё чуть-чуть, и я разбогатею...

Ещё чуть-чуть – и первое число.

Ещё чуть-чуть – и Новый год...

Ещё чуть-чуть, и бой курантов Нам возвестит...

-----------

Думаю, определяющей тут является всё-таки интонация. А её мы можем "услышать" только при помощи знака препинания. То есть, получается немного наоборот: **если** автор хочет передать особую интонацию, он должен ставить тире; если же автор не хочет какого-то особого подчёркивания, - запятую.

Comment: >Я бы поставила тире, так как вторая часть содержит неожиданное присоединение.   
  
Тире, конечно. А что касается несогласия с формулировкой "неожиданное присоединение" - это это опять-таки вопрос терминологии. Лопатин дает более широкую формулировку "на дилетанта" - и все становинтся на свои места.  
И все это, кстати, - тоже к вопросу о какие правила (для первоклашек или заумные) более помогают...

Comment: Вот-вот. Я сначала написала, но потом убрала: "неожиданное присоединение" - очень субъективный термин, кому-то неожиданно, кому-то не очень, и как это определить? У Лопатина, действительно, более удачная формулировка.

Answer (score 2):

Нужна. Это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух простых ("ещё чуть-чуть", "конец"); можно увидеть между ними слабую условно-следственную связь ("если ещё хоть чуть-чуть, тогда...").

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, на тему *чуть-чуть* есть достаточно забавный рассказ, построенный в форме диалога. В нем речь идет о том, как это самое *чуть-чуть* часто у людей борется с "временем Ч" (точкой остановки). Если интересно, то вот ссылка http://prosto-slova.ru/istorii/8-eshchjo-chut-chut-ili-chto-budet-dalshe.html

Answer (score -1):

Неожиданного присоединения при наличии "чуть-чуть" не может быть. Конец как раз ожидаемый. Всё-таки запятая ближе.